# Binary Search Tree in Clojure

Tags: clojure, size, binary-search-tree

I was trying to implement an add function for the BST

```
  (defn size
  "Return the number of nodes in a BST."
  [bst] 
    (cond (nil? bst) 0
    :else (+ 1 (+ size(:left bst)  size(:right bst)) ) )
  )
```

Does this look right?

Comment: This is a valid `size` (not `add`) function, provided both `:left` and `:right` exist for a non-nil node.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things wrong here. You are still calling functions in the "standard" way. `size(:left bst)` will raise an exception, you need `(size (:left bst))` (paranthesis around are important as well as a space after name of the function).

Second thing - no need to use `cond` when you have one case and `:else`. Just use if:

```
(if (nil? bst) 
  0
  (+ 1 (+ (size (:left bst)) (size (:right bst)))))
```